# Sorting A Drop Down Menu in Django With Hard-Coded Choices

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu

I have a few drop down menus that are hard-coded into my model.  For example:

```
CITIZENSHIP_CHOICES = {
    (u'Canada', u'Canada'),
    (u'USA', u'USA'),
    (u'United Kingdom', u'United Kingdom'),
    (u'None', u"None of the above"), 
}

COUNTRY_CHOICES = {
('USA', 'USA'),('Canada', 'Canada'),('Israel', 'Israel'),('UK', 'UK'),('Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan'),('Albania', 'Albania'),('Algeria', 'Algeria'),('Andorra', 'Andorra'),('Angola', 'Angola'),('Antigua and Barbuda', 'Antigua and Barbuda'),('Argentina', 'Argentina'),('Armenia', 'Armenia'),('Australia', 'Australia'),('Austria', 'Austria'),('Azerbaijan', 'Azerbaijan'),('Bahamas', 'Bahamas'),('Bahrain', 'Bahrain'),('Bangladesh', 'Bangladesh'),('Barbados', 'Barbados'),('Belarus', 'Belarus'),('Belgium', 'Belgium'),('Belize', 'Belize'),('Benin', 'Benin'),('Bermuda', 'Bermuda'),('Bhutan', 'Bhutan'),('Bolivia', 'Bolivia'),...
}

SERVICE_LENGTH_CHOICES = {
    (6, "6"),
    (12, "12"),
    (18, "18"),
    (21, "21"),
    (24, "24"),
    (28, "28"),
    (30, "30"),
    (32, "32"),
    (32, "36"),
    (42, "42")
}
```

All of my fields are in the same model in models.py. Each one of the drop down fields looks like this:

`citizenship = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CITIZENSHIP_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)`

For some reason though, in my form, the drop downs are in a strange order. I'd like it either to be in the order I entered it in models.py or to order it alphabetically/numerically.

[image: Service Length drop down menu][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiPeY.png)[image: Country drop down menu][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjmcA.png)[image: Citizenship drop down menu][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrXcr.png)

Everything I've found online discusses foreign keys, but I'm not using any foreign keys.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You've made them all sets, instead of nested tuples. Use round parentheses throughout.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That totally solved the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Daniel Roseman's comment above.  I used {} instead of ()!